# Call swift function in cocoa app from service/quickactions menu in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, applescript

I have developed a cocoa app in MacOs using Swift. At the moment the app has a NSStatusItem button which I'm using to call some Swift functions (`@objc func`). Is it possible to call those functions from within the QuickActions/Services menu instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a specialized service in your app. See: [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).